# updating combo values

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a combo that simply displays some mysql databases.  I also have a form that creates a database.  I would like to dynamicly refresh the combo (if possible) to also display the new database created by the form.  here is a snippet of the code:

```
<div id="tools">

    <P>Add a Set list:<br>
        <LABEL for="labelName">Set List Name: </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" name="slName" id="slName"><button id="createSL" value="Create Setlist">Create Set</button>
        </P><br>
    <P>Delete a Set list:<br>
        <? include("remSLcombo.php"); ?> <button href="#" type="button" id="delSl">Delete Setlist</button>
    </P>
    <p>Check how to reload combos</p>

</div><BR>


    <? include("combo.php"); ?>
```

The Jquery function that is called to create the database:

```
$('#createSL').click(function(){
            var sendIt = $("#slName").val();
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "createSL.php",
                data: {slName : sendIt},
                error: function(e){
                    alert("The PHP Call failed!  hmmm");
                    alert(e.status);
                },
                success:  function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }


            });
           $("#selcombo").load("combo.php");
           $("#tools").hide().html(data).fadeIn('fast');
        });
```

Combo.php:

```
    <?php

echo '<select id="tunelist" name="tunelist" >'; 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'setlist', 'music');
$query = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
echo '<option>Select a Show</option>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ($row['Database'] == "information_schema"){}
    elseif ($row['Database'] == "performance_schema"){}
    elseif ($row['Database'] == "mysql"){}
    else{
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Database'].'">'.$row['Database'].'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</Select>';



?>
```

How do I go about refreshing the values in the combo (made by combo.php) after a database is added using the form above?

Any help as always is greatly appreciated!

Loren

Comment: @Sam I just edited to include the question.  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to give back in `createSL.php` the code of the new combobox and loaded there.

This is your code

```
            success:  function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
```

Write something like:

```
        success:  function(response){
            $('#tunelist').html(response);
        }
```

Where the response is similar to `Combo.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```js
$("#selcombo").load("combo.php");
```

to inside of your `success` function:

```js
success: function(response){
    alert(response);
    if (response == true) // or something like this to ensure the success of the operation
         $("#selcombo").load("combo.php");
}
```

Comment: I tried this.  It appeared that it had an affect but didn't actually rerun combo.php because the new database was not shown.